# Javascript push and wait for async promises in array

Tags: javascript, async-await

I want to wait for an array of **Promises** but I cannot add them without executing them.
So I had to create a wrapper function, however **Promise.all** does not execute them.

This is my code:

```
    const set = new Set(Array.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));

    const func = async (input) => {
        let result = await asyncFunc(input);
        return result;
    }

    var promises = [];
    for(const element of set) {
        promises.push(() => { func(element) });
    }

    await Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
        console.log(values);
    });
```

I exepect **Promise.all executes the func function**, but it does not. How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Why do you expect promise all to execute the func function? `promises` is an array of functions, not promises. Maybe map the array first, calling the function, and pass that result to the promise.all?

Comment: "I cannot add them without executing them" << what's the problem with that? A promise is an asynchronous task that's currently running (or ran in the past) and delivers a result in the future. Of course you can get a promise only by starting that task.

Comment: By the way, why are you mixing `then` with `await`? The last lines should be simply `const values = await Promise.all(promises); console.log(values)`

Comment: The problem is that i cannot get the results.
At the end of the script, values variable is not assigned!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just push promises to your array, not functions:

```
    const set = new Set(Array.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));

    const func = async (input) => {
        let result = await asyncFunc(input);
        return result;
    }

    var promises = [];
    for(const element of set) {
        promises.push(func(element));
    }

    await Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
        console.log(values);
    });
```

Comment: "_but I cannot add them without executing them_" - This _will_ execute them.

Comment: I already tried and like @Ivar correctly pointed out, THIS WILL EXECUTE THEM

Comment: can i know what is asynFunc(input) do?

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem!

The issue of mine was that some of my promises will **reject** and **Promise.all** does not continue when this is the case!

I solved by using **Promise.allSettled**!